# html search and write

Tags: javascript, html

I have long list of links which needs to be more simple for maintaining.

For example all my (100+) urls have similar format:

```
<a href="http://web1.com/AAA">AAA</a>
<a href="http://web2.net/BBB">BBB</a>
```

as You can see different urls contains same text as name of link... so what I need is simplify things with javascript probably. Getting text between tags `"> </a>` and putting him inside href.:

```
<a href="http://web1.com/{script get AAA}">AAA</a>
<a href="http://web2.net/{script get BBB}">BBB</a>
```

any ideas? Thanks

Comment: store the links in php array or angular

Answer (score 1):

So why not just store the links in an `array`?

```
$links = [
            ['domain' => 'web1.com', 'text' => 'AAA'],
            ['domain' => 'web2.net', 'text' => 'BBB']
         ];

foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo "<a href=\"http://$link['domain']/{$link['text']}\">{$link['text']}</a>";
}
```

You could even add more information to the links `array`, if you need.

Comment: This is written in PHP.

Comment: the question has a php tag

Comment: The question also has a javascript tag.

Comment: thanks, this might work, but for this approach needs to be rewritten everything :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other option you can use jQuery to select all the links and edit them.

```
 $('a').each(function() {
      var text = $(this).text()
      var newTarget = $(this).attr("href") + text;
      $(this).attr("href", newTarget);
 });
```

Or, the simpler version:

```
 $('a').each(function() {
      $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + $(this).text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
// a variable with common part of the link
var link ='http://web.com/';
//get all the anchor tags. If a specific anchor tag is need pass
// indetifier like class eg-document.querySelectorAll('a.className')
var getAllAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
/Loop through the collection
getAllAnchorTags.forEach(function(item){
// get the text in the link & concat with the common part
 var creatLink =link+item.textContent;
 // set href attribute to the link
 item.setAttribute('href',creatLink)

})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/n3494odr/)

**Edit**

Let the anchor tag have a default `href` value. Then use `getAttribute` to get the `href` & update its value

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://web1.com/">AAA</a>
<a href="http://web2.net/">BBB</a>
```

**JS**

```
var getAllAnchorTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');
getAllAnchorTags.forEach(function(item){
 var creatLink =item.getAttribute('href')+item.textContent;
 item.setAttribute('href',creatLink)
})
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/n3494odr/2/)

Comment: This is javascript.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i am sorry i could not make anything from your comment

Comment: The question has two tags: javascript and php. An answer can be given in either languages. Sometimes it is not clear to readers which language is used. So I clarified. Some readers don't seem to understand that, which is ironic. Anyway, the answer should have contained at least something like: 'You can do it like this in Javascript'.

Comment: thanks, this is close. but I updated my post because only ending of urls are same with link name.. not the whole url

Comment: ya this is very close... and what if string is not at ending of url but somewhere inside? `http://web1.com/text/AAA/text`

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript and jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var websites[] = "";
        //Websites
        websites[0] = "www.website.com";
        websites[1] = "www.website.net";

        var things[] = "";
        //Pages corresponding to website 0
        things[0] = ["AAA", "CCC"];
       //Pages corresponding to website 1
        things[1] = ["BBB", "DDD"];

        for(x=0;x<websites.length;x++) {
         for(y=0;y<things.length;y++) {
            $("<a href='"+websites[x]+"/"+things[x][y]+"'>"+things[x][y]+"</a>").appendTo("#yourparentelem");
         }
        } 
});
```